# What do we know about the Protocol War?

Tags: jean-le-flambeur, quantum-thief, fractal-prince

The Protocol War is referenced many times in the books.

> As far as I remember, there was no one clear revalation chapter about what the war was about, who were on what sides, and what are the big things that happened because of it.

So, the question is:

> What exactly do we know about The Protocol War so far, based on the references on the books?

I'm interested in answers from any of the books in the series. At the time of this question, these include The Quantum Thief and The Fractal Prince.

Answer (score 1):

Hannu has indicated that we may get answers to some of this - I emphasise *some* - in the third book, The Causal Angel, which is scheduled for publication this April.

Comment: Can't wait to get my hands on the book!

Comment: Though the release date (according to Amazon) seems to be 17 July 2014.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to have slipped - UK release is now June, so I guess other territories may be July. Also annoyed as it's listed as paperback only, and I have the first two in hardback and want this to match.